# How can make corner of triangle using after and before css3 properties

Tags: css, css-shapes

I try to make corner triangle with after and before using border-radius. But can't make it correctly.

[image]

Comment: A simple request on Google could give you multiple solutions.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried (HTML and CSS)

Comment: I've closed it as a dupe because even though the slant is on a different side in the linked answer (and border-radii are smaller), the approaches would be the same. Try using the methods mentioned there and if you get stuck, [edit] in your code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

the after css would be,

```
:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

this was a part of triangle shaped breadcrumps, which you can see in the link below

[CSS Triangle Breadcrumbs](https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/)